# Placing a JFileChooser at a specific location

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on an application in swing and need to place two JFileChoosers on a form. I can't seem to place them at specific locations(it is required that they are placed one next to each other not one above another).
 The code:

```
public class ServerGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
     private JPanel JPanel1 = null;
     private JButton startStopButton = null;
     private JTextField portSelect = null;
     private JLabel portLabel = null;
     private JFileChooser rootDir = null;
     private JLabel rootLabel = null;
     private JFileChooser maintenanceDir = null;
     private JLabel maintenanceLabel = null;
     private JCheckBox maintenanceMode = null;
     private JLabel serverInfo = null;

     ServerGUI() {
       /// create an instance of our server
       webserver = new WebServer();
       /// build form controls -- with default options
       JPanel1 = new JPanel();
       startStopButton = new JButton("Start Server");
       portSelect = new JTextField("10008");
       portLabel = new JLabel("Port:");
       rootDir = new RootChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
       /// choose directories only
       rootDir.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
       rootLabel = new JLabel("Choose web root directory:");
       maintenanceDir = new MainChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
       /// choose directories only
       maintenanceDir.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
       maintenanceLabel = new JLabel("Choose maintenance root directory:");
       maintenanceMode = new JCheckBox("Switch to maintenance mode");
       /// not selected by default
       maintenanceMode.setSelected(false);
       serverInfo = new JLabel("Start");
       /// add controls onto form 
       add(JPanel1, "Center");
       serverInfo.setBounds(0, 0, 20, 10);
       JPanel1.add(serverInfo);
       startStopButton.addActionListener(this);
       startStopButton.setBounds(35, 10, 2, 3);
       startStopButton.setLayout(null);
       JPanel1.add(startStopButton);
       JPanel1.add(maintenanceMode);
       JPanel1.add(portLabel);
       JPanel1.add(portSelect);
       /// set layout for directory choosers
       // rootDir.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
       // rootDir.setLayout(null);
       JPanel1.add(rootLabel);
       JPanel1.add(rootDir);
       // maintenanceDir.setBounds(130, 20, 100, 100);
       // maintenanceDir.setLayout(null);
       JPanel1.add(maintenanceLabel);
       JPanel1.add(maintenanceDir); 
       }
     }
```

I have tried variations between setBounds(), setLocation() for labels, setBound() and setLayout(null) for the button and created an extended class of JFileChooser in an attempt to hardcode the Dlg location.

```
   static class RootChooser extends JFileChooser {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent)
            throws HeadlessException {
          JDialog dlg = super.createDialog(parent);
          dlg.setLocation(0, 40); // new location does not apply
          return dlg;
       }

       RootChooser(String filePath) {
        super(filePath);
       }
    }
```

and

```
 static class MainChooser extends JFileChooser {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent)
            throws HeadlessException {
        JDialog dlg = super.createDialog(parent);
        dlg.setLocation(200, 140); // does not work as expected
        return dlg;
    }

    MainChooser(String filePath) {
        super(filePath);
    }
 }
```

How may I place these controls at specific locations?

Comment: Take a look at MigLayout (http://www.miglayout.com/). It's simple and amazingly easy to create nice layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this

```
maintenanceDir = new MainChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

wont help when `maintenanceDir` is declared as `JFileChooser` you would now be down-casting your custom `JFileChooser` `MainChooser` to a default one `JFileChooser`.

The problem is you dont create an instance of your own custom `JFileChooser` rather a normal `JFileChooser` which does not have your custom `createDialog(Component parent)` method:

```
 ...
 private JFileChooser rootDir = null;
 private JLabel rootLabel = null;
 private JFileChooser maintenanceDir = null;
 ...
```

should be:

```
 ...
 private RootChooser rootDir = null;
 private JLabel rootLabel = null;
 private MainChooser maintenanceDir = null;
 ...
```

Comment: I'll try that but my problem is that I can't seem to control any of the component's location; they are added one after another on my form. You forgot to call the base constructor.

Comment: Tried this right now. Still no effect. rootDir = new RootChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));                          The object is being built properly.